# Asset Pipelining in a simple HTML project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, project

I want to make a simple application using HTML5,CSS3 and JavaScript.
My question is that:

How to do asset pipe lining(as in Ruby on Rails) or equivalent in the project so that one doesnt need to include every Css and Js files in all the respective HTML pages

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ruby on rails, you can choose what javascript file or stylesheet (css) file to load using
    javascript_include_tag 'js_file_you_want_to_load.js'
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag
or
    stylesheet_link_tag 'css_file_you_want_to_load.css'
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag
On the pages you want to include the javascript or stylesheet files
Instead of loading them all in the asset pipeline

If you're not using ruby on rails, you might want to check out [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Is it useful for including css files too?

Comment: If you're talking about requirejs, check out http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html, scroll down to the Loading CSS section